# My font is not working across all devices

Tags: html, css, fonts, content-management-system, google-webfonts

I am trying to make Source Sans Pro font work on my website on devices that don't have the font themselves.  I have had this problem in the past but have never really gotten down to the bottom of it.

This is my website (Disclaimer: I am not the designer):
http://www.nickysfolders.com/?SessionThemeID=34#

I have...
1. put the font-face on the stylesheet where i call the font

```
@font-face
{
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Comic Sans MS;
 src: url('SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf');
}
```

2. called the font

   ```
   .footer-text{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    color: #636466;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    }
   ```
3. and I have downloaded and put all font .ttf files on the server in a location where the font-face can access them, directly in the **same** css folder

I expected that this would work on all the computers I tested it on but it doesn't.  Instead it fellback to times new roman or sans serif?  This is why I made the fallback comic sans so I know, if it is actually accessing it in the first place. Apparently it isn't?

Thank you for your time.  Please let me know if I should provide any other details.

Comment: `src:` will look for a file relative to the CSS file. Try using an absolute (`http://...`) URL, or one that's relative to the `/` root directory, here instead. Also: `Comic Sans MS` should be in quotes.

Comment: Read [this mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face) then try again

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can import using the `<link>` tag in HTML...

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
```

or this CSS import...

```
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro');
</style>
```

You can customize which variants you'd like to use too over on [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro?selection.family=Source%20Sans%20Pro).

Once you've linked or embedded the font file from Google or your own server, then `font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;` should work just fine.

Comment: Hey man thanks but i should be able to do it using either way... to be clear tho I have linked it like you suggest however the way i specify above is the most safe/compatible.  I was looking for someone to tell me what I did wrong above. Maybe a dumb mistake.  Or maybe a step I have overlooked.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not very familiar with the method you posted so unfortunately I can't to speak to what may be wrong. I've only used the methods I outlined and have not had any issues. Best of luck to you in your project.

Comment: Dude the computers I am required to test on are ancient and in a sad state I'm not surprised. One of them is a Windows machine with a mac keyboard 